# XSD skip validation of whole structure beneath a given node

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'd like to include some generic and unknown XML content in my own XML. 
Therefore, I'd like to skip the validation of a specific node in my XML file.

I'm trying to get all the content beneath my node `parentField` skipped from validation using the following XSD. But it seems that it is only skipping the first level of my XML subtree as part of `parentField`. Are there any solutions to include a generic XML as part of your own XML using `xs:any` or other hacks suggested such as pasting it as CDATA?

```
<xs:complexType name="MyType" final="">
  <xs:all minOccurs="0">
    <xs:element name="parentField">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:any minOccurs="0" processContents="skip"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example does, in fact, skip validation of a whole structure beneath the `parentField` element because of your use of `xs:any` with `@processContents="skip"`, ***provided there's only a single child under `parentField` since `maxOccurs` defaults to `1`, and provided that there's no mixed text under `parentField`***.

Making the accommodations for the above two provisions,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="r" type="MyType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="MyType" final="">
    <xs:all minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element name="parentField">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

will more fully allow arbitrary markup under `parentField`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r>
  <parentField>
    <v/>
    All
    <x>
      of this
      <y>
        content
        <z>is now allowed</z>
        under parentField.
      </y>
    </x>
  </parentField>
</r>
```

as requested.